# Passing events to a jQuery-plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I just started writing Plugins for jQuery. I found a good tutorial how to start with it, but one point I missed. I want register a independent plugin-object for each element and I need them events.

Here the code I got atm:

```
(function($){
     var MyPlugin = function(pElement, pOptions)
     {
        var element = $(pElement);
        var object = pElement;
        var settings = $.extend({
           param: 'defaultValue'
        }, pOptions || {});

        this.onfocus = function() {
            element.val('Focus');
        };

        this.onblur = function() {
            element.val('Blur');
        }

        // DO I NEED THIS?
        object.onfocus = this.onfocus;
        object.onblur = this.onblur;
    };

    $.fn.myplugin = function(options)
    {
        return this.each(function()
        {
            var element = $(this);
            if (element.data('myplugin')) { return };
            var myplugin = new MyPlugin(this, options);
                element.data('myplugin', myplugin);

        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Do I need to copy my public methods "onfocus" and "onblur" from "this" to "object"? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best guide for writing jQuery plugins is probably [jQuery's own](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

[jQuery's event system](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) is the best way of handling events for your plugin. If you're using jQuery 1.7+ (which I recommend, if it's possible), `.on()` and `.off()` are your workhorses. Not only can you bind browser events like **focus** and **blur**, you can create completely custom events like 'iamasuperstar' and trigger them manually with `this.trigger( 'iamasuperstar' )`.

So you'd do something like this for your plugin:

`element.on( 'focus', function() {} )`

`element.on( 'blur', function() {} )`

...and whatever else you need.

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
    object.onfocus = function() {
        element.val('Focus');
    };

    object.onblur = function() {
        element.val('Blur');
    }
```

Comment: Damn, it's so easy. I thought it were more complex and I could not use my object properties. Thank you!